# Where to put "ViewPager.setCurrentItem()" Method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment-lifecycle

I have Nested `Fragments` [1 main `Fragment` called "MainFrag" and many child `Fragments`]
the App can show MainFrag or can show other fragments.

what I want to do is to `setCurrentItem` of MainFrag's `ViewPager` every time the user selects to show that MainFrag so I tried to put it at it's `onCreateView` but this only works for the first time the User Shows MainFrag as if user Selects another fragment and then re-selects MainFrag the `seCurrentItem` is not working

I also tried to put it inside MainFrag's `onResume`, It worked as required but it also causes a problem that if the user moved the App to background and then reOpen it viewPager will Scroll and i don't want this

So where Exactly Can I put `setCurrentItem` ?

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mCurrentWeekFragmentItemNumber);
```

Edit: I am using Navigation Menu to Move between 3 main fragments where MainFrag is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);` method you can put

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mCurrentWeekFragmentItemNumber);
```

Comment: I have 3 Main fragments on of them is `MainFrag` which contains some childs. what u r saying works only first time I shows `MainFrag` but if a scrolled to some child and then showed up another Main fragment from the 3 and then reShow my `MainFrag` the `currentViewPager` item is Still the same from last time.  `setCurrentItem` does not work again.

Answer (score 1):

After setting adapter to viewpager add setCurrentItem method

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mCurrentWeekFragmentItemNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

    }
```